# Schedule Jenkins Job every 2 and half Hour

Tags: jenkins, cron

I need to schedule a Jenkins job which need to **build every 2 and half hour(every 150 minute)**. I have checked google but haven't find a useful link which help me with this, most of the links are referring to whole number hour's.

Also is it possible to run a Jenkins Job **every 30 seconds** and **every 1 minute**.

When I tried for every 1 minute `*/1 * * * *` it was running for every 1 hour instead of 1 minute.

Any guidance on this will be very helpful.

Comment: What is an actual use case for running a Jenkins job every 30s? This seems a little odd.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple lines of repeated/scheduled executions.

```
0 */5 * * *
30 2-23/5 * * *
```

First execution: By the beginning of every fifth hour. 
`0:00 5:00 10:00 15:00 20:00`

Second execution: By the half of every fifth hour starting at 2:30am. 
`2:30 7:30 12:30 17:30 22:30`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.So for these every 30 seconds and every 1 minute? Any info on this?

Comment: @Linu When it runs every 30s, it also runs every minute because 1min is an integer multiple of 30s = 1/2min.

Comment: "*/2 * * * *"This is not working for every 30 seconds, but it works for every 2 minute, see the below results.  "Would last have run at Tuesday, July 30, 2019 11:32:12 AM CEST; would next run at Tuesday, July 30, 2019 11:34:12 AM CEST."

Comment: Any idea on how to schedule it for 30 seconds, i searched a lot but didn't find an exact answer for this.

Comment: @Linu Again my question: What is an actual use case for triggering every 30s? This seems like an  [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me...

Comment: The thing is that i have two servers one server where my magento commerce site is running & other my Data ware house.The data from the main server is ported every 20 min to the DWH. This DWH server is used for my reporting purposes.So we need one report that ideally shows the near REAL TIME values of the main server,So i have created a PY script for porting the data from source to DWH and it took only 7-10 sec max for it's execution and is scheduled via Jenkins. Since we need a near real time values in the report i'm planning to execute the job every 30 sec.Hope i made it clear.

Comment: There must be a different way than doing this with Jenkins. It seems very inappropriate. You maybe should consider to have a python script running the whole time through, polling the data and putting it into a file. You really should not trigger the data acquisition by Jenkins, but instead have an infinite loop inside the Python Script.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

`30 */2 * * *`

Comment: I think this will execute every second hour in the 30th minute.

Comment: @Giovanni Patruno Thanks for the reply.So for these every 30 seconds and every 1 minute? Any info on this?

Comment: @Giovanni Patruno This is not working , Below is the result "Would last have run at Tuesday, July 30, 2019 10:30:37 AM CEST; would next run at Tuesday, July 30, 2019 12:30:37 PM CEST."